# Cannot Get XSLT IF To Return Xml

Tags: xslt

I want to copy the  elements that match when

```
SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 99
```

OR

```
SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 12
```

Here is a snippet of the`XML

```
<trade>
<PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
<TICKER>F</TICKER>
<SECURITY_TYPE>1</SECURITY_TYPE>
<SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>99</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
<PRICE>17.98</PRICE>
<QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
</trade>
<trade>
<PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
<TICKER>C</TICKER>
<SECURITY_TYPE>1</SECURITY_TYPE>
<SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>12</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
<PRICE>3.42</PRICE>
<QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
</trade>
<trade>
<PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
<TICKER>AAPL</TICKER>
<SECURITY_TYPE>2</SECURITY_TYPE>
<SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>4</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
<PRICE>300.34</PRICE>
<QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
</trade>
```

Here is my failed XSLT. What could be wrong?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
<xsl:copy>
<xsl:if test="(SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 99) or
(SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 12)">

<xsl:value-of select="."/>

</xsl:if>
</xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: The XML sample is not valid (there is no single root element).

Comment: As a first try, exchange the copy and the if element. Usually testing before copying gives better results than the other way round.

Comment: Good question, +1. See my answer for an explanation of the likely problem in your solution, and for a short and easy solution that uses the identity rule design pattern. Complete explanations are provided. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seemes that you are trying to produce something like the identity rule, but you are missing the `<xsl:apply-templates>` part and your transformation does not go deeper at all.

**Here is a short and easy solution**:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
 <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
     <xsl:copy>
       <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
     </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match=
  "trade[not(SECURITY_TYPE = 1)
       or
         (not(SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 99)
       and
          not(SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 12)
          )
         ]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when this transformation is applied on the provided XML document** (wrapped by a single top element to make it well-formed):

```
<t>
    <trade>
        <PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
        <TICKER>F</TICKER>
        <SECURITY_TYPE>1</SECURITY_TYPE>
        <SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>99</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
        <PRICE>17.98</PRICE>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
    </trade>
    <trade>
        <PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
        <TICKER>C</TICKER>
        <SECURITY_TYPE>1</SECURITY_TYPE>
        <SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>12</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
        <PRICE>3.42</PRICE>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
    </trade>
    <trade>
        <PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
        <TICKER>AAPL</TICKER>
        <SECURITY_TYPE>2</SECURITY_TYPE>
        <SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>4</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
        <PRICE>300.34</PRICE>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
    </trade>
</t>
```

**the wanted, correct result is produced**:

```
<t>
   <trade>
      <PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
      <TICKER>F</TICKER>
      <SECURITY_TYPE>1</SECURITY_TYPE>
      <SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>99</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
      <PRICE>17.98</PRICE>
      <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
   </trade>
   <trade>
      <PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
      <TICKER>C</TICKER>
      <SECURITY_TYPE>1</SECURITY_TYPE>
      <SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>12</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
      <PRICE>3.42</PRICE>
      <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
   </trade>
</t>
```

**Explanation**:

1. **The [identity rule](http://dpawson.co.uk/xsl/sect2/identity.html) (template) copies all nodes "as-is".** Using and overriding the identity rule is the most fundamental XSLT design pattern.
2. **There is a single additional template that overrides the identity rule for any `trade` element that doesn't satisfy the required selection properties**. This template has no body and thus it causes the transformation not to process at all (delete) any `trade` element that doesn't satisfy the required conditions.
3. **As result of 1. and 2. above, only `trade` elements (and their complete sub-trees) that satisfy the required conditions are copied to the output**.

Comment: This works Dimitre. I was also able to make another transformation to get the <trade> elements where SECURITY_TYPE = 7 and 11

trade[not(SECURITY_TYPE = 7)
       and not(SECURITY_TYPE = 11)]

However, I am stumbling into logic pruning trying to get ALL these variations:

SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 1
SECURITY_TYPE = 7 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE > 0
SECURITY_TYPE = 11 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE > 0 111 ANY NUMBER
2 0

Comment: @user584537: Glad my answer was useful. Here at SO, the way to express gratitude is to accept an answer (just clik on the green checkmark next to the answer). :)

Comment: However, I am stumbling trying to get ALL these variations:

SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 1
SECURITY_TYPE = 7 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE is any number
SECURITY_TYPE = 11 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE is any number
SECURITY_TYPE = 2 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 0 

Yields too many conditions I think, so I get a blank result set.

trade[not(SECURITY_TYPE = 7)
       and
         not(SECURITY_TYPE = 11)
       and               
         (not(SECURITY_TYPE = 1)
       and
          not(SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 1))
       or
         (not(SECURITY_TYPE = 2)
       and
          not(SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 0)

Comment: I discovered the answer

 <xsl:template match=
  "trade[not(SECURITY_TYPE = 7)
       and
         not(SECURITY_TYPE = 11)
       and               
         (not(SECURITY_TYPE = 1)
       or
          not(SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 1))
       and
         (not(SECURITY_TYPE = 2)
       or
          not(SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 0))
         ]"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>

Comment: I checked the GREEN. Thank you Dimitre for your answer and very helpful explanation.
-Kevin Novick

Answer (score 1):

Use the identity transformation template plus one template suppressing copying of the elements not matching the condition:

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="trade[not((SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 99) or (SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 12))]"/>
```

If that does not do what you want then post the result you want to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

This stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
    <xsl:template match="trade[SECURITY_TYPE != 1
                               or SECURITY_SUB_TYPE != 99
                                  and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE != 12]"/>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Output: (with wellformed input, of course):

```
<root>
    <trade>
        <PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
        <TICKER>F</TICKER>
        <SECURITY_TYPE>1</SECURITY_TYPE>
        <SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>99</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
        <PRICE>17.98</PRICE>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
    </trade>
    <trade>
        <PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>123</PORTFOLIO_NUMBER>
        <TICKER>C</TICKER>
        <SECURITY_TYPE>1</SECURITY_TYPE>
        <SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>12</SECURITY_SUB_TYPE>
        <PRICE>3.42</PRICE>
        <QUANTITY>1</QUANTITY>
    </trade>
</root>
```

Answer (score 0):

I added a root element of <trades>.  The solution below works.  You must apply the conditional logic only to the <trade> element, not all elements.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl"
>
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>


  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- parse the <trade> element -->
  <xsl:template match="trade">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:if test="(SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 99) or
        (SECURITY_TYPE = 1 and SECURITY_SUB_TYPE = 12)">

        <xsl:value-of select="."/>

      </xsl:if>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```